# Still plot lower bound of CI when upper limit is missing

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Currently I have some data with estimates and lower and upper bounds that I would like to plot as CIs. However some of my estimates do not have an upper bound. When I try to plot the CIs it removes the whole CI instead of just the upper limit. I would still like the lower limit to be plotted. Are there ways to plot the lower limit even when the upper limit is missing. `ggplot2` or base `plot` answers are fine.

Here is the error

> Warning message: Removed 1 rows containing missing values
>   (geom_errorbar).

Data

```
    structure(list(trials2 = c("A", "B"), surv = c(9.4, 18.4), drug_site2 = c("Site X", 
"Site X"), lower = c(5.7, 17.3), upper = c(13.8, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

plot

```
ggplot(data = survs2)+
  geom_point(aes(x=drug_site2,y=surv,color=trials2),size=3)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = drug_site2,ymin = lower, ymax = upper,color=trials2))+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous("Median Survival (Months)", limits = c(0,60))+
  scale_x_discrete("")
```

[image]

Update: Here is what was reported in the paper for the results

From the text :

> The median survival time was 18.4 (95% CI, 17.3, NR) and 13.6 (95% CI,
>   11.3–15.8) months in the drug and placebo arms, respectively.

Image from paper:
[image]

Comment: Is the upper limit really missing all together or `Inf`?  You can't have an interval without one side. :)  So depending on what you feel is justified, you could choose a value for the top of the interval, such as the estimate of the median for the observation to just show the lower "half" of the interval.

Comment: `survs2 <- survs2 %>% mutate(upper = ifelse(is.na(upper), surv, upper),
                            lower = ifelse(is.na(lower), surv, lower))`
This will set the limit which is `NA` to the actual `surv` value. But for the sake of proper practice consider @aosmith response

Comment: @aosmith Unfortunately the data comes from a published manuscript where they only reported the lower bound and I do not have access to the data to find the upper bound. @Croote that is a good suggestion but I do not want to mislead the readers to think that the upper limit is actually very close/identical to the survival. `Inf` will allow for the CI to be plotted but the line will just extend off the graph

Comment: I don't think you've done a good job of describing the results. What does it mean to say you have a "surv" of 9.4? Without a good description of what sort of estimate this is we cannot make grounded inferences about how the CI's were estimated. (If they were simply regression coefficients then they were probably published in error. But that seems unlikely given the value of 18.4 having a relatively narrow lower bound interval from the estimate.)

Comment: @42- The estimates come from an unadjusted KM curves, `surv` is median survival time in months. The paper only published the lower bound of this estimate to show that the new treatment was more effective than the standard of care at that time. I can't tell if they used linear CIs or log-log CIs in the paper.

Comment: Did they publish the curves? (the axis label did suggest these were months, i.e. survival times) (if the original report used just a table to present the results it doesn't make a lot of sense to construct a plot for two points.)

Comment: @42- yes they did publish the curves. My real plot contains more data than the current one, I only provided enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can we look at the graphic?

Comment: @42- I added the figure and the information provided from the text of the paper.

Comment: If you are calculating a median for times in a censored set and only 2 of the members have uncensored times (and all the values must be greater than the last event)  then the last then calculating an 95% CI will not be possible. I would argue that this is done in the setting of the human lifespan and the upper limit would be less than 120 years, rather than infinity but why not plot using a large value but restrict the plot to regions of interest.

Comment: @42- If you plot a larger value say 80 months in my case it and restrict the view to 60 months the whole CI will be dropped, specifying `Inf` will show the line extend off the graph.

Comment: Exactly; that is the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to my problem. After the discussion above I still think that showing the lower limit and no upper limit is important. 'Not reported' is not the same as 'upper limit not reached' and I think this is a true missing value/simply not reported (for whatever reason).

The workaround is to use `geom_linerange` twice to span once from lower to estimate and then from estimate to upper bound. The lower bound is there, just very small.

```
ggplot(data = survs2)+
  geom_point(aes(x=drug_site2,y=surv,color=trials2),size=3)+
  geom_linerange(aes(x = drug_site2, ymin = lower, ymax = surv, color = trials2))+
  geom_linerange(aes(x = drug_site2, ymax = upper, ymin = surv, color = trials2))+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous("Median Survival (Months)", limits = c(0,60))+
  scale_x_discrete("")
```

[image]